# iOS touch up inside on disabled button

Tags: ios, uibutton

If a `UIButton` has been disabled by `[myButton setEnabled:NO];` is it possible to use a touch listener that still works?

I have tried:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTUI:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is No

```
enabled
A Boolean value that determines whether the receiver is enabled.

@property(nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
Discussion
Specify YES to make the control enabled; otherwise, specify NO to make it disabled. 
The default value is YES. If the enabled state is NO, the control ignores touch 
events and subclasses may draw differently.
```

Can you simulate such functionality? Yes.

Instead of disabling the button, make a check to see if the functionality should fire on the buttons action selector. You can even change the image to make it look disabled. This way the button still receives touch events, and you can fire the required functionality if the correct conditions are met.

Comment: There's got to be a better solution than this. Can't we just attach another gesture recognizer to the button?

Comment: For the record, I achieved this by placing the button inside a `UIView` and attaching a gesture recognizer to the `UIView`. For some reason it didn't work when attaching it directly to the button.

Comment: You'll have problems with accessibility going this road.

Comment: @rshev this is a super old question/answer, but what do you mean?

Comment: @ColdLogic UI tests detecting if a button is enabled will always get true, which is unacceptable for QAs

Comment: @rshev true. That is more of a problem with your QA team than this solution though. That would be your QA or Designer telling you to enable  or disable the boolean flag on the control, which probably isnt actually their goal. Adding the tap gestures like other comment suggest basically overrides the buttons functionality in a very unsafe way IMO.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by wrapping the `UIButton` in a `UIView` of the same size and attaching a tap gesture recognizer to the parent view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonHit)];
[self.myButtonView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to work when attaching the gesture recognizer to the `UIButton` itself, which would have been the nicest solution.